# Totally positive unit a square?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, integer-lattices

Let $ \mathcal{O}$ be an order in a totally real number field $E$, then $( \mathcal{O},q_1 )$ is an integral lattice with its natural  quadratic form $q_1(x):=\text{tr}_{E/\mathbb{Q}}(x^2)$ (which is positive definite). Also, if $u$ is a totally positive unit in $ \mathcal{O}$, then the form $ q_2(x):=\text{tr}_{E/\mathbb{Q}}(u \,x^2)$ give us another positive definite lattice $( \mathcal{O},q_2 )$.

When $u$ is a square unit, say $u=v^2$, this lattices are actually isometric by the map $\phi:( \mathcal{O},q_1 )\rightarrow( \mathcal{O},q_2 )$ given by $x \mapsto v^{-1} x$. Now, I've been trying (for a while) to deal with the reciprocal question, i.e.,

**If there exists an isometry $\phi:( \mathcal{O},q_1 )\rightarrow( \mathcal{O},q_2 )$, then must $u$ be a square ?.**

So far all I've been able to say is that if exist $\kappa \in \mathcal{O}$ such that $\phi(x)=\kappa \, x$  for all $x\in \mathcal{O} $, then $\text{tr}_{E/\mathbb{Q}}(x^2)=\text{tr}_{E/\mathbb{Q}}(u \, \kappa^2 x^2)$ implies $\text{tr}_{E/\mathbb{Q}}((1-u \, \kappa^2) x^2)=0 \,\, \forall x \in \mathcal{O} $,  but then $1-u \, \kappa^2$ would be  $q_1-$orthogonal to all $\mathcal{O}$ and therefore $u=\kappa^{-2}$, however I have no idea how to prove (or if it is even possible to prove) that $\phi$ must be of this form for some $\kappa$.

I'm especially interested  in the case  where $E$ is an $S_3$ cubic field (its normal closure has Galois group $S_3$). I haven't been able to find any counterexamples in this setting, I'd be more than grateful if someone could give some idea of how to find one.

I also would like to know if there are some reference where to find things related to this sort of problems. Thanks in advance!.

---

**Update:** Although quadratic fields it's not my purpose I realized that there at least two $n$  for which the question is false for the quadratic field $E=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})$ and  maximal order $\mathcal{O}=\mathcal{O}_E$. These are $n=3,7$ with nonsquare units $u$ equal to  $2+\sqrt{3}$ and $8+3\sqrt{7}$ respectively.

Indeed, the Gramm matrix of $q_i$ ($i=1,2$) always have determinant equal to $\text{disc}(\mathcal{O})$, thus $\frac{1}{2}q_i$ is a primitive form of discriminant $-4 n$ in both cases, and thefore it correspond to an ideal class in the order $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$ of conductor $2$ in $\mathcal{O_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-n})}}$, but since in both cases the class number $h\left(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]\right)=1$, we have that $\frac{1}{2}q_1$ and $\frac{1}{2}q_2$ are equivalent and therefore $q_1$ and $q_2$  isometric.

These are actually the only cases in which we can use the "class number 1 trick", because none the other quadratic orders of class number 1  works. Could we do something similar for cubic fields?.

---

**Edit**: I made a mistake in the last update, even though the forms I mentioned do have discrimiant $-4 n$ not all of them are primitive which make the argument invalid.

In fact, for this forms is true that isometry implies the unit is a squre (It's enough to note that the form asociated to the fundamental unit it's not equivalent to $2(x^2+n y^2)$ ). So, the matter is still open even for quadratic fields.

---

**Update 2:** I'm going to try to focus in one case, give some examples, present some evidence and make the statement more elementary as @reuns suggest.

Let's focus in the quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})$ with $n$ a positive square free integer  $n \equiv 3 \,\text{mod} \, 4$, and its maximal order $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}]$.

Acording to [A031396](http://oeis.org/A031396) all of this fields will have totally positive fundamental units (because if $a^2-n b^2=-1$  is soluble and $n$ is odd then $ n\equiv 1 \,\text{mod} \, 4$). So let $u=a+b\sqrt{n}>1$ with $a^2-n b^2=1$ be the fundamental unit, the Gramm matrix of the form we asociate to $u$ and to $1$ in the basis $\{1 , \sqrt{n} \}$ are repectively

$\left[\begin{array}{cc}\text{tr}(u )  & \text{tr}(u\sqrt{n} ) \\\text{tr}(u \sqrt{n})  & \text{tr}(u\, n ) \end{array}\right]=2 \, \left[\begin{array}{cc}a & n b\\ n b & n a\end{array}\right] \,$ and $ \,\left[\begin{array}{cc}\text{tr}(1 )  & \text{tr}(\sqrt{n} ) \\\text{tr}(\sqrt{n})  & \text{tr}(\, n ) \end{array}\right]=2 \, \left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\ 0 & n \end{array}\right].$

now since, as noted in the begining, the forms associated to square units are isometric to the associated to $1$, there will be a nonsquare unit with form equivalent to $q_1$ iff this two forms are isometric (that's why I say it's enough to check for the fundamental unit).

When $a$ is even (for example for $n=3$ and $n=7$ with  $u=2+\sqrt{3}$ and $u=8+3\sqrt{7}$ respectively), the forms are non even equivalent over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ ( because mod 4 one is $\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 2\\ 2 & 0 \end{array}\right]$ and the other $\left[\begin{array}{cc}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{array}\right]$ ).

So the more interesting case would be when $a$ is odd (for example for $n=39$ with $u=25+4\sqrt{39}$), in this case both $\frac{1}{2}q_1=x^2+n y^2$ and $\frac{1}{2}q_2=a x^2+2 b n \, xy+ n a \, y^2$ are *primitive*  forms of discriminant $-4n$. And the question could be rephrased as

**Is it possible for $a x^2+2 b n \, xy+ n a \, y^2$  to be equivalent to $x^2+n y^2$?**

Or in the language of ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$

**Is it possible for the ideal  $\langle a, -b n+\sqrt{-n} \rangle_{\mathbb{Z}}$  to be principal?**

I wrote the this code in Magma which shows that this is never the case at least for $n<20000$

```
         > for l in [0 .. 5000] do
         >n:=4*l+3;

             > if IsSquarefree(n) then
                > K := QuadraticField(4*n);
                >v:=FundamentalUnit(K);
                >a:=Abs(Trace(v)/2);
                >b:=Abs(Trace(v*K.1)/(2*n));
                > M1 := Matrix(2, [1,0,0,n]);
                > M2 := Matrix(2, [a,n*b,n*b,n*a]);
                >L1:=LatticeWithGram(M1);
                >L2:=LatticeWithGram(M2);

                 > if  IsIsometric(L1,L2) then
                 > n;
                 > break l;
                 > end if;
                > end if;
       > end for;
```

Comment: It is definitely not true that totally positive units are squares; look at the cubic field with conductor 163, or at the quadratic field with discriminant 12.

Comment: @reuns, thanks for your answer, I've made my best to be more clear and give a concrete statement, What do you think?.

Comment: So you ask if the ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$ whose coefficients come from the fundamental unit of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}]$ is principal ? Isn't that weird ?

Comment: I know it sounds crazy, but I get there from the general consideretions in an albitrary totally real field, and so far the evidence suggests that in the quadratic case that ideal it's never principal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the answer is positive and it is much easier than you think.

Let $K$ be a totally real number field of degree $n$, for any totally positive integral element $x\in K$, we have
$$\mathrm{tr}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(x)\geqslant n\sqrt[n]{\mathrm{N}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(x)}\geqslant n.$$
and $\mathrm{tr}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(x)=n$ if and only if $x=1$.

For any order $\mathcal{O}$ in $K$ and a totally positive unit $u\in\mathcal{O}$, denote $q_1(x):=\mathrm{tr}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(x^2)$ and $q_2(x):=\mathrm{tr}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(ux^2)$. If $\phi:(\mathcal{O},q_1)\to(\mathcal{O},q_2)$ is an isometry, then
$$\mathrm{tr}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(u\phi(1)^2)=q_2(\phi(1))=q_1(1)=n$$
which implies $u\phi(1)^2=1$, so $u=\phi(1)^{-2}$ is a square.

Comment: Thanks, I thought of using the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality before, but never got it to work, briliant!.And just in time.

Comment: If it's not too much, Can I make one more question?. What if $v$ is another totally positive unit , $q_3(x)=\mathrm{tr}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(vx^2)$ and there is an isometry $\phi:(\mathcal{O},q_2)\to(\mathcal{O},q_3)$, could this method be use to prove $u \, v^{-1}$ is a square?

Comment: @Theodor There are counterexamples. Let $K$ be the splitting field of $f(x):=x^3-6x^2+8x-1$, then the $3$ roots of $f(x)$ are totally positive units which give isometric quadratic forms, while the pairwise ratios are not squares. However, I guess it might be true for $S_3$ cubic fields, but I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: (wow!) according to Magma your example is correct. How did you  to find it?

Comment: @Theodor Since $\mathrm{tr}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\sigma(v)\sigma(x)^2)=\mathrm{tr}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(vx^2)$ for $\sigma\in\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$, it is natural to consider Galois conjugation, while other conditions can be fulfill without much efforts.

Comment: In the same spirit of your example we have that in the cyclic cubic field $K$ defined by $x^3-x^2-234x+729$ the three units roots of $x^3-41 x^2+326x-1$ give us another counterexample, but what make you think we could prove it for $S_3$ cubic fields?